# Injection $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]{\bf\big\backslash}\left\{ 1/n : n\in \mathbb{N}^*\right\}$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f$ continuous at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Does there exist a function $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]\setminus\left\{\frac 1n, n\in \mathbb{N}^*\right\}$ so that $f$ is 1-1, $f(0)=0$ and $f$ continuous at $0$? Does it have a closed form?

I know that as $[0,1], [0,1]\setminus\left\{\frac 1n, n\in \mathbb{N}^*\right\}$ have the same cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, at least one bijection between them exists. By swaping $0,x$ ($x$ is the unique number for which $f(x)=0$) I can obtain $f(0)=0$. But what about continuity at $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $n\in\mathbb N$ the intervals $\left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right]$ and $\left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right)$ have the same cardinality. Therefore there are functions 
$$\phi_n:\left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right]\longrightarrow\left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ 
which are $1-1$ (and onto).
For example $\phi_n(x)=\dfrac{(n+1)x+1}{2(n+1)}$.
Define 
$f:[0,1]\to [0,1]\setminus\left\{\frac 1n, n\in \mathbb{N}^* \right\}$ 
with 
$f(0)=0$ 
and 
$f(x)=\phi_n(x)$ 
if 
$x\in\left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right]$.

Answer (score 2):

For each $n$, choose any bijection $g_n:]\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]\to]\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}[$.

Then define $f$ using the functions $g_n$: for each $x$, $f(x)=g_n(x)$ such that $x\in]\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$, and of course $f(0)=0$.

You can show that $f$ fulfills all the requirements.